# Nested each statements aren't working

Tags: ruby, each

I'm trying to write a program in Ruby that finds the prime factors of a given number, without using Ruby's .Prime class. The code I wrote seems logical (if roundabout) to me, but for some reason the last line of code doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why. The code still just returns all of the factors of a given number, not the prime ones.

```
def prime(n)
    array = []
    r = Range.new(2, n - 1)
    r.each { |x| array << x if n % x == 0 }
    array.each { |x| puts x if (2..x - 1).each { |p| x % p != 0 }}
end
```

Comment: `(2..x - 1).each { |p| x % p != 0 }` wont return anything, so the `if` will never be evaluated to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check [`.all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) numbers in `(2..x - 1)`, not `.each`:

```
def prime(n)
  array = []
  r = Range.new(2, n - 1)
  r.each { |x| array << x if n % x == 0 }
  array.each { |x| puts x if (2..x - 1).all? { |p| x % p != 0 }}
end
```

By the way, I would also recommend to give meaningful names to your variables, because now it's really hard to read your code, this is much clearer implementation:

```
def prime?(num)
  return false if num < 2
  (2..Math.sqrt(num).to_i).each do |i|
    return false if num % i == 0
  end
  true
end

def prime_factors(num)
  (2..num - 1).inject([]) do |factors, i|
    (num % i == 0) ? factors << i : factors
  end.select { |factor| prime?(factor) }
end

p prime_factors(44)
```

Comment: Your `prime?` function will have runtime error when given a negative number.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yes, thanks. don't mind my previous question, I found it out

Answer (score 1):

```
def prime_factors(n)
    # It's clear what factors will hold.
    # It helps you when you or someone else read it out 
    # after a while.
    factors = []

    # Keep the r. No problem.
    r = Range.new(2, n-1)

    # Array#select is nice for this task.
    # select is good in case where you need to filter out certain
    # values out of a list. It nicely separates the selection task.
    factors = r.select { |x| n % x == 0 }

    # It's better not to go for double block on a single line.
    # It will become more readable this way.
    # Also it's better to handle how the result is displayed outside
    # the function and just to return the computed values.
    factors.select do |x| 
        (2..x - 1).all? { |p| x % p != 0 }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems more logical to split this single function into three `factors n`, `prime n`, and `prime_factors n` then compose them together. This design is more modular and more suitable to testing the individual parts. e.g. If all of the logic is globbed together, how can you say for certain that your program find primes correctly?

```
def factors n 
   (2..(n/2).floor).select {|x| n % x == 0 } 
end

def prime? n
   return false unless n >= 2
   (2..Math.sqrt(n).floor).all? {|x| n % x != 0 }
end

def prime_factors n
   factors(n).select {|x| prime? x }
end
```

Comment: Your `prime?` method is invalid. It'll return true for 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks, missed that tiny piece. I find that behavior of `.all?` interesting though; e.g. this `[].all? {|x| false }` returns true as well